# EBNF interpretation of the grammar

Tags: parsing, tree, ebnf

How can I interpret this as ENBF grammer?

```
<assign>--> <id> = <expr>

<id>--> A | B | C

<expr> --> <expr> * <expr>

<expr> --> <expr> + <expr>

| <id> + <expr>

|( <expr> )

| <id>
```

---

I can make parse tree and derivation of any statement using this grammer, but am having trouble with EBNF.

Comment: Looks like its in BNF already (which is a subset of EBNF), so no changes are needed (though it is ambiguous).  Is there a question here?  What 'trouble' are you having with EBNF?

Answer (score 0):

```
<assign>--> <id> = <expr>
```

An `assign` is the sequence: `id` equals-sign `expr`.

```
<id>--> A | B | C
```

An `id` is one of `A`, `B` or `C`

```
<expr> --> <expr> * <expr>
<expr> --> <expr> + <expr>
| <id> + <expr>    
|( <expr> )    
| <id>
```

An expression can be:

1. The product of two expressions (infix notation)
2. The addition of two expression (infix notation)
3. The addition of an identifier and an expression (which is a particular case of addition of two expressions, where the first expresion is just `<id>`)
4. A parenthesized expression.
5. An identifier.